# can't connect to web3 using websocket method

Tags: web3.py

I'm trying to connect to web3 using the websocket method and i keep getting errors. It works fine when I use the HTTP method, but for some reason WSS isn't working. any idea what im doing wrong? thanks!

```
from web3 import Web3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
import uniswapv2abi
import requests


version2abi = uniswapv2abi.UNIVTWO_ABI
UNISWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS = Web3.toChecksumAddress(("0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D").lower())
weth_contract_address = "0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2" 
eth_node_url = "https://nd-061-866-537.p2pify.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
eth_addy_final = Web3.toChecksumAddress(("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").lower())
eth_private_keys = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"


wss_node_url = "wss://ws-nd-061-xxx-xxx.p2pify.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
web3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider(wss_node_url))

status = web3.isConnected()
print(status)
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 3):

turns out the script was fine. it was the WSS endpoint that wasn't working.